# Jquery plugin: Jplayer dynamic playlist

Tags: jplayer

please somebody help me with this... im using jplayer plugin to play music on my website.

**javascript:**

```
var cssSelector = {
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1", 
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        };
        var playlist = []; // Empty playlist
        var options = {
            swfPath: "/js", 
            supplied: "mp3"
        };
        var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'process/getmusics.php',
            cache: true,
            async: false,
            type: 'post',
            data:{
                category: category,
                moodrate: rate,
            },success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                var music  = $.parseJSON(data);
                myPlaylist.add(data); 
            }


        });
```

**php:**

```
$sql = "SELECT
            `musics`.`file_name` as mp3
        FROM
            `categories`
            INNER JOIN `musics` 
                ON (`categories`.`id` = `musics`.`category`)
        WHERE (`categories`.`category_name` =?
            AND `musics`.`rate` =?)";
$result = $con->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(1, $category);
$result->bindParam(2, $rate);

$data=0;
if($result->execute()){
    while($r = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $data = $r;
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

now my ajax return a correct data but the problem is in my jplayer..

**generated error by console:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"mp3":"Passenger - Let Her Go.mp3"},{"mp3":"Secondhand Serenade - Maybe.mp3"}]

please help..